# Regex not working on Python (older version)

Tags: python, python-2.7

After parsing a text to its desired format, I had to run it on another machine that has an older version of python than the one I used,

The regex that I used in my local machine is this one:

```
splitty = [re.sub(r"(.*?)\-\d+\-\d+\-(\d+)", r"\1=\2", i) for i in splitty]
```

But seems like it is not working in the other one.

I have tried looking at the documentation of python 2.7 and for similar answers, but I am not finding a way to transform it to Python 2.7

The actual result is:

```
11.22.233.122/19\name_of_machine\t8\t8\t0
```

The desired one is:

```
11.22.233.122/19\name_of_machine=0
```

Input string:

```
10.101.0.240/29\tname1\t8\t8\t0
14.101.0.222/29\tname2\t8\t8\t0
11.101.2.211/29\tname3\t8\t7\t1
10.121.2.22/26\tname4\t64\t63\t1
11.201.0.214/29\name5\t8\t6\t2
```

Comment: Can you please add information about what your expected result and your actual result are ?

Comment: @andymeissner I have already edited my question.

Comment: Could you also give the input string?

Comment: just use `strip()` it's tab chracters.

Comment: @andymeissner I have already edited my post with the input string.

Answer (score 1):

First, I can't get your code to work under Python 3 either. Second, what you claim to be the input string does not appear to be correct: the last line has `\name` instead of `\tname` and I suspect this is in error. And as far as your "desired output" is concerned, I can only assume that the "name of the machine" is to be taken from the last number on the line judging from your regex.

```
import re

s = """10.101.0.240/29\tname1\t8\t8\t0
14.101.0.222/29\tname2\t8\t8\t0
11.101.2.211/29\tname3\t8\t7\t1
10.121.2.22/26\tname4\t64\t63\t1
11.201.0.214/29\tname5\t8\t6\t2"""

splitty = s.split('\n')
splitty = [re.sub(r"(.*?)\t\d+\t\d+\t(\d+)", r"\1=\2", i) for i in splitty]
print(splitty)
```

Prints:

```
['10.101.0.240/29\tname1=0', '14.101.0.222/29\tname2=0', '11.101.2.211/29\tname3=1', '10.121.2.22/26\tname4=1', '11.201.0.214/29\tname5=2']
```

You were looking for `-` characters (which did not need to be escaped) rather than tab characters between the numbers.